# Soldering multiple resistors in series

Tags: resistors, soldering, wiring

I'm starting the wiring for my project and would like to solder two resistors together in series. There is good chance that the wire will be exposed to heat and gentle turbulence.

**What is the best way to solder axial-lead resistors?**

I have seen that twisting the metal wires from each resistor is a good technique. Is this the same for the electrical wiring? Should the electrical wire be twisted with the resistor wire when soldering?

I was also thinking that if there were to be slight turbulence, would it be a better idea to put an electrical wire between the resistors so that the solder doesn't get damaged by movement?

I will be protecting the resistors and wiring with good quality heat wrap for added protection although the electrical wire is rated for high temp use and is very durable. The resistors are also more resistant to heat than standard ones so they cost a little bit extra (talking pennies though!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't mention exactly what kind of resistors they are, but for "normal" through hole ones the best way is to first wrap one resistor's leg around the other resistor's leg, then wrap that resistor's leg around the first resistor's leg.  So you end up with this:

[image]

The resistors hold themselves together and make it really easy to solder.  It's a tough connection that won't easily break.

Depending on the kind of wire you're using you can use the same technique.  It's also common to "insert" the resistor lead into the middle of the strands of stranded wire for soldering.

Comment: This is what I was thinking

Comment: clarified that they are axial-lead resistors in the post

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method, for high quality chassis wiring, is to use turret terminals staked into a G-10 (FR-4) board to capture the components, and then to make the required connections at the appropriate terminals, like this:

[image]

Comment: This looks good but I think is more complex than what I need for two resistors. It does look incredibly neat though!